# How to dependency inject database clients into structs in golang?

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I am trying to use dependency injection to inject a database client in the struct using go language. Unfortunately, I did not understand how this could be done as i only see basic examples in the internet from which i am unable to get complete picture.

I have a Producer interface which is having different implementations. I also have a client for redis/kafka to produce messages.

```
package producers

type IProducer interface {
    setMessageType(messageType string)
    setTopic(topic string)
    getMessageType() string
    getTopic() string
}

type Producer struct {
    messageType string
    topic       string
}
// producer implements the IProducer

type UserLocationProducer struct {
    Producer
}

func newUserLocationProducer() IProducer {
    return &UserLocationProducer{
        Producer: Producer{
            messageType: "user_location",
            topic:       "user_location",
        },
    }
}
```

Redis client code

```
type RedisClient struct {
    pool *redis.Pool
}

func NewRedisClient(addr string, dn int, passwd string) *RedisClient {
    // code to create client
    return client
}
```

Now my question is if i want to inject RedisClient into Producer how can i achieve it. I am basically from Java background where i will wire my dependencies using  Spring and Autowiring the dependency. Any pointers is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection can be done here by using interfaces, which act as a commonality between the different clients, e.g. below is one of the ways this can be done.

A Client interface that both kafka/redis clients satisfy

```
type Client interface{
    Publish(<message etc fields>)
}

func (redisClient RedisClient) Publish(<message etc fields>){
    //Do client things
}
```

IProducer: new method to set client (kafka/redis).

```
type IProducer interface {
    ...
    SetClient(client Client)
}
```

Producer: field for reference to the client, and setter method,

```
type Producer struct {
    ...
    client Client
}

func (producer Producer)SetClient(clt Client){
    producer.client = clt
}

func (producer Producer)send(){
    client.Publish(<message etc fields>)
}
```

Client interface can be mocked for testing and injected same way into Producer

Also Instead of `SetClient` method field `client` can be set directly while creating Producer, Just that setter methods give a bit more control.